# simpy 2.2 examples in 3.0

Tags: python, simulation, simpy

I am trying to work through some of the examples of simpy 2.2 (see: https://pythonhosted.org/SimPy/Tutorials/TheBank2OO.html) and rewrite them using simpy 3.0 lexicon (see: http://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/about/history.html). Has anybody came across the the following example (bank door opens) rewritten for 3.0? Im not entirely sure how to write the "self.sim.door_open" in the "customer" class as an event using simpy 3.0.

```
from SimPy.Simulation import     Simulation,Process,Resource,hold,waituntil,request,release
from random import expovariate,seed

##Model components ------------------------

class Doorman(Process):                                       
    """ Doorman opens the door"""
    def openthedoor(self):
        """ He will open the door when he arrives"""
        yield hold,self,expovariate(1.0/10.0)                 
        self.sim.door = 'Open'                                           
        print "%7.4f Doorman: Ladies and "\
              "Gentlemen! You may all enter."%(self.sim.now(),)

class Source(Process):                                        
    """ Source generates customers randomly"""
    def generate(self,number,rate):       
        for i in range(number):
            c = Customer(name = "Customer%02d"%(i,),sim=self.sim)
            self.sim.activate(c,c.visit(timeInBank=12.0))
            yield hold,self,expovariate(rate)

class Customer(Process):                                      
    """ Customer arrives, is served and leaves """
    def visit(self,timeInBank=10):       
        arrive = self.sim.now()

        if self.sim.dooropen():
            msg = ' and the door is open.'         
        else:
            msg = ' but the door is shut.'
        print "%7.4f %s: Here I am%s"%(self.sim.now(),self.name,msg)

        yield waituntil,self,self.sim.dooropen                         

        print "%7.4f %s: I can  go in!"%(self.sim.now(),self.name)     
        wait = self.sim.now()-arrive
        print "%7.4f %s: Waited %6.3f"%(self.sim.now(),self.name,wait)

        yield request,self,self.sim.counter
        tib = expovariate(1.0/timeInBank)
        yield hold,self,tib
        yield release,self,self.sim.counter

        print "%7.4f %s: Finished    "%(self.sim.now(),self.name)                                 

## Model  ----------------------------------

class BankModel(Simulation):
    def dooropen(self):                                               
        return self.door=='Open'

    def run(self,aseed):
        self.initialize()
        seed(aseed)
        self.counter = Resource(capacity=1,name="Clerk",sim=self)
        self.door = 'Shut'
        doorman=Doorman(sim=self)                                          
        self.activate(doorman,doorman.openthedoor())                    
        source = Source(sim=self)                                                         
        self.activate(source,
             source.generate(number=5,rate=0.1),at=0.0)    
        self.simulate(until=400.0)

## Experiment data -------------------------

maxTime = 2000.0   # minutes    
seedVal = 393939

## Experiment  ----------------------------------

BankModel().run(aseed=seedVal)
```

What i have so far, but i get the error "Environment object has no attribute 'door_open'"

```
import simpy
import random
```

Ninja edit: I managed to get the simulation to run, however i cant get the door to initialize as "closed" then open at some point.

```
def openthedoor(self):
    yield self.timeout(random.expovariate(1.0 /10.0))
    print('%7.4f Doorman: ladies and gentleman you may enter' %(self.now))



def source(env, name, counter):

     for i in range(500):
        env.process(customer(env, 'Customer%02d' % i, counter,      time_in_queue=30.0))
        t = random.expovariate(1.0 / 20.0)
        yield env.timeout(t)

def customer(env, name, counter, time_in_queue):
    arrive = env.now

    if env.process.openthedoor(env):
        msg = 'and the door is open'
    else:
        msg = 'but the door is sht'
        print('%7.4f %s: Customer has entered queue and' % (arrive, name, msg))

    yield env.process(openthedoor(env))
    print('%7.4f %s: I can go in' % (env.now, name))
    wait = env.now - arrive
    print('%7.4f %s: Waited %6.3f' % (env.now, name, wait))

    with counter.request() as req:
        # Wait for the counter or abort at the end of our tether
        yield req 
        waited = env.now - arrive
        tib = random.expovariate(1.0 / 20.0)
        yield env.timeout(tib)
        print('%7.4f %s: Waited %6.3f' % (env.now, name, waited))
        print('%7.4f %s: Finished' % (env.now, name))

print('Batch Record Review Simulation')
random.seed(RANDOM_SEED)
env = simpy.Environment()
data = []
counter = simpy.Resource(env, capacity=1)
env.process(source(env, CUSTOMERS, counter))
# Start processes and run


env.run(until=SIM_TIME)
```

Answer (score 0):

In SimPy 2, `waituntil` used “busy waiting”, that means it checked at each step if the condition evaluates to `True`.  This is not very good practice and may consume a lot of CPU time.  That’s why this is no longer in SimPy 3.

In SimPy 3, you would use a normal `Event` (as created by `Environment.event()`).  You could, for example, create a `Door` class and pass a reference to the door instance to the door opener and the customer(s).  The customer could do a `door.open = env.event()` every time they want to open the door.  The door opener would then trigger that event.

An alternative solution might be to use a `PriorityResource` (or maybe `PreemptiveResource) as door.  The door opener uses a higher priority than the customers and is thus able to “block” the door (== door closed).  Once the door opener releases the resource, the next customer can “open” the door.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! As an aside, do you think it would be possible to use a priority resource in such a way to cyclically (over a regular, non-random interval) open and close the door? Perhaps using a separate thread to change the resource priority relative to the system clock (every minute) and set to simulation to run in real-time? From what i have read, changing resource capacity over time is non-trivial. Maybe I am misunderstanding how threading works? At any rate, thanks again.

Comment: You cannot change the capacity of the built-in resources. You’d have to write your own type to achieve that.